# Why would an array try to access beyond it's bounds in a for-loop?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I've never seen this happen before. I have an NSArray populated with 6 objects. I loop through the array grabbing the values, using just an average, simple for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= self.myArray.count; i++) {
        CustomClass *stopTimes = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Hey this number %d: at this time  %lld", i, stopTimes.theTimeRange.start.value);
    }
```

When this loop runs,it crashes due to accessing only 1 index beyond the array, every time. In this case there are 6 items, it crashes trying to access the sixth.

So, I go to the LLDB and confirm that there are indeed 6 objects in the array:

```
(lldb) po self.myArray
<__NSArrayM 0x16bf8620>(
<NeededObject: 0x16bf9f40>,
<NeededObject: 0x16ceO1c0>,
<NeededObject: 0x16ce4268>,
<NeededObject: 0x16cf0b75>,
<NeededObject: 0x16b06d22>,
<NeededObject: 0x16b02240>
)
```

But... The NSLog that I have in my loop prints out only 5 objects.
I have no idea why the loop is trying to access outside of it's bounds. There are hacks to get around this (such as setting i = 1, etc).

Comment: <= count will take you one index too far.  Change to strictly <

Comment: In other words, the range of an array is `0` to `count - 1`.

Comment: (Facepalm) Beginner's mistake, thank you so much everyone!

Comment: It's actually a very well known, shared error (everybody has done this at some point) http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error  You might consider using fast-enumeration (for-in) loops, which make this error impossible, and will probably run more efficiently :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overstepping the bounds by going right up to the count as an index. Change the loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.myArray.count; i++)
```

Notice the change from `<=` to `<`.

If an array has three elements, the indices will be 0, 1, 2 and the count will be 3. Therefore, looping from 0 to the count will result in counting 0, 1, 2, 3; where 3 is outside the bounds.

Comment: (Facepalm) Beginner's mistake, thank you so much Wes!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `for (int i = 0; i < self.myArray.count; i++)`

`.count()` gives you length of the array. As indices start from 0, you can go only upto `length of the array - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

An array runs from index '0' to index 'count-1'. You're running your array to index 'count'.

You should run your loop this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.myArray.count; i++) {
    CustomClass *stopTimes = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Hey this number %d: at this time  %lld", i, stopTimes.theTimeRange.start.value);
}
```

The difference is '<' instead of '<='.